# How to assign trusted certificate to local domain?

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04

i install Jenkins on tomcat 9 behind nginx , i want to assign trusted certificate to get rid of the "your connection is not private" message.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to become local domain secure (SSL) you can use Laragon Software.
[image]

first of all create hostname and
enable ssl port 443 (Apache) or 8080 (Nginx)

[image]